# how to select last price in invoice table where item code =? and customer =?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have table for invoice details like item code ,item price and customer and i want to find last price for one item where customer 
how can do that in SQL server with vb.net

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select top1 item_price from tb_creditsales_inv where inv_cust= @cust and inv_item =@invitem order by id decs", connSql)
```

what mistake in this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; you should provide at the bare minimum the design of your tables (maybe some sample content), and a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish. it seems you want to find the last price your customer paid for a item for essentially a e-commerce website. If you are looking for some assistance in the code; some guidance on what you have so far would be helpful also

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think if you have a date field you can use an 'order by desc' and, therefore, list from the last to the oldest and, since you already have a conditional, it will be much easier to obtain the record you want. .

If you want a more secure filter, use a date and time field to avoid getting confused if you are on the same date.

Comment: can you explain how to do that by sql code ? please

Comment: select table item,datetime where item code =? and customer =? order by datetime limit number

Comment: you must create your date and time field

Comment: @JordyValenzuelaValcarcel the OP said this is a SQL Server query. SQL server does not support the LIMIT keyword.